# When using an image in a fragment, the image is shown on some pages, but not other. Why?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a fragment like this:

```
   <header th:fragment="navbar">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-info navbar-dark">

                <a th:href="@{/main}"><img th:src="@{logo.png}" alt="Sauna" class="navbar-brand" style="height:45px"/></a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('USER')" class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/wall}">Lauteet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('USER')" class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/saunojat}">Etsi saunoja</a>
                        </li>
                        <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('USER')" class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{'/saunojat/' + ${#authentication.name}}">Oma profiili</a>
                        </li>
                        <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')" class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/notifications}">Yksityisilmoitukset</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </nav>
    </header>
```

The uppermost item in this navbar, the <a/a> set is showing up the image on some pages of my project, but on other it it is showing the "Sauna" string  from the alt parameter in addition to the picture not found standard logo. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you forgot to specify the url of pages where it works and where not, so it's kind of a educated guess answer without that.

However, I say a red flag in the markup you posted and most likely that is the problem (aside your security configuration that you figure it out). It's about the attribute `th:src="@{logo.png}"` and the way it will resolve.

The way you wrote it, it is a relative path, so it will resolve against your current URL.

To give an example, let's say your app has the base URL `http://localhost:8080`. With a relative path, it will search the image in `http://localhost:8080/logo.png`. Problem is that you navigate on `http://localhost:8080/admin/users`, now the image src will resolve to `http://localhost:8080/admin/users/logo.png` which most likely will result in a 404 status.

To make an absolute path to the file regardless of your current url, you must change the src attribute to `th:src="@{/logo.png}"`. The `/` before the name indicates that it will be resolved against root of your domain, not the current URL (relative).

Another solution would be specifying explicitly the base URL for relative links in the HTML head. The same result as the absolute path would be achieved by adding in the `<head>` section of your HTML, the `<base href="http://localhost:8080/" />` to indicate that the relative links in your file should resolve against that path.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This actually makes sense, because now that I think, the pages where it did not work had url:s exaclty like you said, behind another path, just like this: http://localhost:8080/admin/users. And now when  I tried, the security configuration works like a charm again by allowing access straight to the file. It just happened that I did by mistake correct the path to an absolute path. The thing is, that I could have sworn that I had tried it with a dash in the very beginning, because it looked funny without it :D But clearly that was not the case! Once again, thank you.

Comment: I would give you an up-vote, but i don't have enough points to do that..

Comment: @mortar-1 It would help if you can accept my answer by clicking the grey checkmark under the votes. I think [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is the process detailed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem seemed to be with Spring security..

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       
        
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/main").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/logo.png").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/notifications").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/main")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/main")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/wall", true)
                .failureUrl("/main?error=true")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/main?logout=true");
    }
```

The problem seemed to be that I was permitting access to the logo.png file itself (it was located in the root of the public folder. I created a folder (public-images) to to the root of public -> moved the file in there. And corrected the html image source to match the new location. And when permitting access to the new folder, everything works fine..

```
... antMatchers("/public-images/**").permitAll() ...
```

Still: WHY DID IT WORK FOR CERTAIN  PAGES AND NOT FOR OTHERS BEFORE THEESE CHANGES ??? :D